# Path to local files for Android Webview

Tags: caching, xamarin.forms, android-webview

I use Xamarin Andorid Webview. 
I cached Audio Files and now will i this Files playd via WhatsApp from Cache/Local
But i don't know what Path should i insert in HTML audio source.

html exmaple:

```
<audio _ngcontent-dgk-c22="">
   <source _ngcontent-dgk-c22="" src="/storage/emulated/0/**/**/**/02212020/54a1cfbf-d5be-45b0-8d22-377d760a7b7d.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

in Xamarin access allowed:

```
 if (this.Control != null)
        {
            this.Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
            this.Control.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
            this.Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            this.Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            this.Control.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            this.Control.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            this.Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            this.Control.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;

            this.Control.SetWebViewClient(new AndroidCustomWebViewClient(string.Format("javascript:{0}", JAVASCRIPTFUNCTION)));

            var chromeClient = new FileChooserWebChromeClient((uploadMsg, acceptType, capture) =>
            {
                MainActivity.UploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                switch (acceptType)
                {
                    case "image/*":
                        ((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(this.CreateChooserForImages(uploadMsg), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                        //PermissionsSetting.Instance.SetPermissionsAsync(PermissionsTask.Camera | PermissionsTask.Microphone | PermissionsTask.Storage);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //PermissionsSetting.Instance.SetPermissionsAsync(PermissionsTask.Storage);
                        ((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(this.CreateGetContent(), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                        break;
                }
            });

            this.Control.SetWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use cached files manually, you can refine your question by clarifying your requirement, and then we'll able to see if there's any workaround.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I am creating a hybrid app with Android Weview with Xamarin. I have pictures that should open offline. I download them to /storage/emulated/0/AppFolder . How can i refer to them in HTML ? Now i will convert them to base64, but it slows down. in thoery it should work like this src = "file:///storage/emulated/0/AppFolder/image.jpeg", but i have error Not allowed to load local resource –

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript’s same origin policy will restrict your webpage to load data from a different origin, in this case, calling webview.LoadData() with a file:///storage/... in the html won't be able to load the picture in local system, since the picture is not under the same origin with your html.

To avoid this restriction, you can use [loadDataWithBaseURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))() as google recommended.

Here is a sample:

```
string htmlStr = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>" +
                 "<h2> HTML Image </h2>" +
                 "<img src ='sample.png' alt = \"Trulli\" width = \"500\" height = \"333\">" +
                 "</body></html>";
string imageDir = "file:///data/user/0/com.companyname.webviewcachedemo/files/";
mWebview.LoadDataWithBaseURL(imageDir, htmlStr, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Nicole Lu, it already found i, but i have 1000 and  more pictures. Also my page is dynamic

Comment: If pictures are in the same fold, maybe you can read your html page into string and append <img> at runtime.

Comment: and by the way this doesn't support in android versions 10 and up.